# xampp woudn't open: You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a little work at hand that I'd need xampp/wamp server. I just installed xampp but it would not open. it just responded now that:

> 'You don't have permission to access / on this server'

Comment: Just follow the instructions on this page http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html. Make sure it's all in `C:\xampp\ `.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why all that I tried didn't work, I later observed that all the applications (xampp and wamp) that I installed were `32 bits` and my system is `64 bits`. Guessed this was supposed to work but it didn't. I downloaded the `64 bits` of wamp which is working perfectly on my system now though still checking out why the `32 bits` apps didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you have to listen that error. Check your folder permission with chmod. You must be have the root access to do that. Btw, did you using Linux or Mac as a server..?

Comment: dont understand what you said i should do. i'm using windows7

Comment: I input this IP on ma browser: 127.0.0.1, it brought the xampp for windows page, it reports that mysql and ftp service components are deactivated.

Comment: and then activated it from xampp control panel. Have you done yet..?

Answer (score 0):

Have you closed Skype? It blocks a port needed by XAMPP.

Comment: I've closed skype and even uninsr=talled it. uninstalled wamp, installed xampp, still giving me the same issue.

Comment: I input this IP on ma browser: 127.0.0.1, it brought the xampp for windows page, it reports that mysql and ftp service components are deactivated.

Comment: @Tongues As I already advised in my comment beneath your post: follow the instructions on http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html - it's all explained there (especially the paragraph "The Practice"). You need to start the Apache and the MySql server - they are both listed in the control panel (`C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe`). Your stuff goes into the `\htdocs` folder then. If you put a `test.html` there, you can call it with `http://localhost/test.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the logs (mainly apache errors log).
Can you please provide more information? for example, xampp on windows you do not have problems with permissions,if linux you will need to pay attention on this issue.

please provide your environment.

Comment: hello Costa, i'm running my xampp on windows7 ultimate to be precise

Comment: I input this IP on ma browser: 127.0.0.1, it brought the xampp for windows page, it reports that mysql and ftp service components are deactivated.